# IntelliJ: Quickly show file path

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I see the file path of the current file I am editing in IntelliJ? I can hover over the tab for a file, but it takes a few seconds and I have to keep my mouse still to see the path, which I can't copy.

Comment: In the title bar of the application, does the file path not appear there?  It does for PhpSstorm and PyCharm, but I don't have IntelliJ installed on this machine to check.

Answer (score 16):

If you just want to copy the file path you can use `Ctrl + Shift + C`.

You can also search for action with (Ctrl + Shift + A) (for mac Command + Shift + A) and then it will show you the Keyboard shortcut for particular action.

[image]

If you want to change the Keymap you can open setting page and search for Keymap.

[image]

If you look at the picture there is a Keymap for `File Path` which will open a pop up like below

[image]

Which is also shows the file path.

Answer (score 6):

View->Appearance->Navigation Bar (check)

[image]